Load data from multiple firestore databses to bigquery using Stream Firestore to BigQuery extension
The scenario
I have 2 Firestore databases in my project xyz-dev and xyz-prod
I want to use the extension Stream Firestore to BigQuery to push this data from Firestore to prod.
Please note there is no firebase app in this project as we don't need one
The Issue
When I try installing the data I don't get the option to "select" the database at all and when I look the underlying cloud function created it has the database URL as blank.
How can I achieve this? is there a way to use the CLI to specify the database?
the configurable parameters don't seem to allow a place to specify database



After much research it seems this is not possible. It seems that the extension is designed to ONLY work with the database named (default). Firebase is not designed to have multiple firestores. You can have Mutiple firestores but all of the firebase utilities can only be used by a firestore databases named (default) . The otehr databses are "invisible" to extensions of firebase
